# error: resource mapping not found || make sure CRDs are installed first

Tags: kubernetes

> error: resource mapping not found for name: "ingress-srv" namespace: "" from "ingress-srv.yaml": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1"
> ensure CRDs are installed first

I am new to Kubernetes, I was setting up ingress nginx on minikube and it installed successfully but when I try to run using kubectl apply -f filename it gives above error

here is the code
filename: **ingress-srv.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - host: posts.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /posts
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              serviceName: posts-clusterip-srv
              servicePort: 4000
```

Comment: What is your kubernetes version? `$ kubectl version --short`

Comment: @Royal thapa Has your issue been resolved? If yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as a solution and accept it?

Answer (score 33):

The resource type specified in your manifest, `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 Ingress`, was removed in Kubernetes v1.22 and replaced by `networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress` (see the [deprecation guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#ingress-v122) for details). If your cluster's Kubernetes server version is 1.22 or higher (which I suspect it is) trying to create an Ingress resource from your manifest will result in exactly the error you're getting.

You can check your cluster's Kubernetes server version (as Kamol Hasan points out) using the command `kubectl version --short`.

If the version is indeed 1.22 or higher, you'll need to modify your YAML file so that its format is valid in the new version of the API. This [pull request](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/89778) summarises the format differences. In your case, `ingress-srv.yaml` needs to be changed to:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - host: posts.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /posts
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: posts-clusterip-srv
                port:
                  number: 4000
```

Comment: I've already followed this configuration, but nothing working for me.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use kubectl convert plugin which was made for upgrading old resource version to new ones. It's installation is available for different OS and is well instructed in K8 docs.

tl;dr
For linux: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/

Step 1)
curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"

Step 2)
sudo install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl-convert /usr/local/bin/kubectl-convert

Step 3)
kubectl convert -f old.yaml > new.yaml

Step 4)
Use new.yaml as you require.