# Error: error: resource mapping not found for name: "dashboard-ingress" in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I am trying to apply ingress rule in minikube but I am getting this error

```
error: resource mapping not found for name: "dashboard-ingress" namespace: "kubernetes-dashboard" from "Desktop/minikube/dashboard-ingress.yaml": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "networking.k8.io/v1"
```

dashboard-ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: dashboard-ingress
    namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
    rules:
    - host: dashboard.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend: 
            serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
            servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 7):

I have found the solution

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dashboard.com
    http:
      paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/"
          backend:
            service:
              name: kubernetes-dashboard
              port:
                number: 80
```

Comment: This is works, but the full answer is here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73211621/2550985